# Create a rainbow radial glow background on photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gradient

wasn't sure how to phrase this so I thought I'd post an example of the kind of effect I'm looking for.

[image]

I understand that this could simply be made with the gradient tool but not sure how to get the 'spread'

any help would be massively appreciated.

Comment: I think those are just several gradient layers, so possible duplicate of https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/128391/gradient-depth-effect-how-can-we-achieve-this-gradient ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gradient depth effect - How can we achieve this gradient?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/128391/gradient-depth-effect-how-can-we-achieve-this-gradient)

Answer (score 3):

It looks like it might just be a regular linear gradient that has been masked using a radial gradient.

You can create custom gradient using the gradient editor.

For example:

[image]

Then over a black layer, I filled a new layer with the Rainbow gradient I made. Then I used a black and white gradient to create a layer mask consisting of a radial gradient, which I stretched into an oval.

For example:

[image]

Comment: Perfect Billy, thanks for the advice

Comment: one minor suggestion: sometimes gradients suffer from banding. An easy way to avoid the banding problem is to make a document set to 16-bits-per-channel RGB; make the gradient; then convert the document mode to 8 bits per channel. You get some dithering noise but there will be no banding.

Comment: @Yorik - absolutely.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case the problematic colored area  is the smaller one which contains everything that a rainbow has you can try this:

Have a black background layer. Then you make the colored shape to a new layer. In Photoshop you can draw a path, convert it to selection and and fill the selection with a gradient:

[image]

(sorry for irregular looking path, you can get easily better result in Illustrator where working with paths is much more comfortable - copy the result and paste it to Photoshop)

Then apply Gaussian blur:

[image]

If the edges seem too thin, undo and try smaller blur radius.

You can also duplicate the layer once or more times and merge the duplicates. It can be a good idea to squeeze the duplicates vertically to avoid the shape becoming too high. It's tried here:

[image]

If you merge the gradient shape with black BG before blurring it's possible to restore the gradient fidelity to some degree with curves:

[image]